# how to make a slidable panel that can be dragged?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a slidable panel just like

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

but I don't want the auto-scrolls, which I mean

the panel can have only 0 size or full screen...

I want the panel to be draggable to have various sizes due to user's adjustments

Is there any library like this?

I'm searching on the web for hours for this particular problem

please help